# Improving my code for project euler p12. in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am doing project Euler.problem twelve and have come up with the following code, which works fine when tested against low numbers:

```
def highlyDivisibleTriangularNumber(n):
    """
    triangular num formula: x(x-1)/2
     e.g 5th triang num: x5 = 5(5+1)/2 = 15

    :param n:
    """
    divisors = [x for x in xrange(1, 31)]
    count = 0
    for i in xrange(1, n):
        triangNum  = (i* (i+1)/2)         # create triangular number based on formula: x(x-1)/2
        for div in divisors:
            if triangNum % div == 0:      # if triangular number modulo div equals 0 the add it to highestDivisors
                count +=1
                if count == 6:              # if count  is equal to 6 then  we have found the  required number so return it.
                            return triangNum
            else:
                if div == 30:                      # else if we have have reached the  last divisor, reset count to zero
                    count = 0

print(highlyDivisibleTriangularNumber(100))
```

I would appreciate some pointers on how to improve efficiency, where I am going wrong  and also in regard to setting the divisor upper limit. 
I am sure from a maths perspective, there are no doubt many ways to improve the code.
Thanks.

The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:

1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...

Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:

1: 1
 3: 1,3
 6: 1,2,3,6
10: 1,2,5,10
15: 1,3,5,15
21: 1,3,7,21
28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.

What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

Comment: Probably should be on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @iCodez my code has not gotten me the correct answer so I don't think it is suitable for codereview?

Comment: Oh, I missed that.  I thought you said it worked and you just wanted it improved.

Comment: It'll be better if you provide the exact problem statement not requiring to visit Project Euler's website and searching for problem No. 12.

Comment: it is fine when I try to get 28, which is the example on the problem page but I need the triangular number that has 501 divisors I am a bit lost on a couple of things and my code is too slow

Comment: You need to make the number of combinations of all prime factor of that number and the numbrr before equal to 500. Also 2^9 = 512 and x and x-1 are coprime.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I don't fully understand what you mean, could you explain it in more detail or give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

```
# a list pre calculated of  prime below 1000, I just don't want to write the
# cal prime code here, it is not the bottleneck
prime_list= [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223, 1229, 1231, 1237, 1249, 1259, 1277, 1279, 1283, 1289, 1291, 1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 1361, 1367, 1373, 1381, 1399, 1409, 1423, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 1447, 1451, 1453, 1459, 1471, 1481, 1483, 1487, 1489, 1493, 1499, 1511, 1523, 1531, 1543, 1549, 1553, 1559, 1567, 1571, 1579, 1583, 1597, 1601, 1607, 1609, 1613, 1619, 1621, 1627, 1637, 1657, 1663, 1667, 1669, 1693, 1697, 1699, 1709, 1721, 1723, 1733, 1741, 1747, 1753, 1759, 1777, 1783, 1787, 1789, 1801, 1811, 1823, 1831, 1847, 1861, 1867, 1871, 1873, 1877, 1879, 1889, 1901, 1907, 1913, 1931, 1933, 1949, 1951, 1973, 1979, 1987, 1993, 1997, 1999, 2003, 2011, 2017, 2027, 2029, 2039, 2053, 2063, 2069, 2081, 2083, 2087, 2089, 2099, 2111, 2113, 2129, 2131, 2137, 2141, 2143, 2153, 2161, 2179, 2203, 2207, 2213, 2221, 2237, 2239, 2243, 2251, 2267, 2269, 2273, 2281, 2287, 2293, 2297, 2309, 2311, 2333, 2339, 2341, 2347, 2351, 2357, 2371, 2377, 2381, 2383, 2389, 2393, 2399, 2411, 2417, 2423, 2437, 2441, 2447, 2459, 2467, 2473, 2477, 2503, 2521, 2531, 2539, 2543, 2549, 2551, 2557, 2579, 2591, 2593, 2609, 2617, 2621, 2633, 2647, 2657, 2659, 2663, 2671, 2677, 2683, 2687, 2689, 2693, 2699, 2707, 2711, 2713, 2719, 2729, 2731, 2741, 2749, 2753, 2767, 2777, 2789, 2791, 2797, 2801, 2803, 2819, 2833, 2837, 2843, 2851, 2857, 2861, 2879, 2887, 2897, 2903, 2909, 2917, 2927, 2939, 2953, 2957, 2963, 2969, 2971, 2999, 3001, 3011, 3019, 3023, 3037, 3041, 3049, 3061, 3067, 3079, 3083, 3089, 3109, 3119, 3121, 3137, 3163, 3167, 3169, 3181, 3187, 3191, 3203, 3209, 3217, 3221, 3229, 3251, 3253, 3257, 3259, 3271, 3299, 3301, 3307, 3313, 3319, 3323, 3329, 3331, 3343, 3347, 3359, 3361, 3371, 3373, 3389, 3391, 3407, 3413, 3433, 3449, 3457, 3461, 3463, 3467, 3469, 3491, 3499, 3511, 3517, 3527, 3529, 3533, 3539, 3541, 3547, 3557, 3559, 3571, 3581, 3583, 3593, 3607, 3613, 3617, 3623, 3631, 3637, 3643, 3659, 3671, 3673, 3677, 3691, 3697, 3701, 3709, 3719, 3727, 3733, 3739, 3761, 3767, 3769, 3779, 3793, 3797, 3803, 3821, 3823, 3833, 3847, 3851, 3853, 3863, 3877, 3881, 3889, 3907, 3911, 3917, 3919, 3923, 3929, 3931, 3943, 3947, 3967, 3989, 4001, 4003, 4007, 4013, 4019, 4021, 4027, 4049, 4051, 4057, 4073, 4079, 4091, 4093, 4099, 4111, 4127, 4129, 4133, 4139, 4153, 4157, 4159, 4177, 4201, 4211, 4217, 4219, 4229, 4231, 4241, 4243, 4253, 4259, 4261, 4271, 4273, 4283, 4289, 4297, 4327, 4337, 4339, 4349, 4357, 4363, 4373, 4391, 4397, 4409, 4421, 4423, 4441, 4447, 4451, 4457, 4463, 4481, 4483, 4493, 4507, 4513, 4517, 4519, 4523, 4547, 4549, 4561, 4567, 4583, 4591, 4597, 4603, 4621, 4637, 4639, 4643, 4649, 4651, 4657, 4663, 4673, 4679, 4691, 4703, 4721, 4723, 4729, 4733, 4751, 4759, 4783, 4787, 4789, 4793, 4799, 4801, 4813, 4817, 4831, 4861, 4871, 4877, 4889, 4903, 4909, 4919, 4931, 4933, 4937, 4943, 4951, 4957, 4967, 4969, 4973, 4987, 4993, 4999, 5003, 5009, 5011, 5021, 5023, 5039, 5051, 5059, 5077, 5081, 5087, 5099, 5101, 5107, 5113, 5119, 5147, 5153, 5167, 5171, 5179, 5189, 5197, 5209, 5227, 5231, 5233, 5237, 5261, 5273, 5279, 5281, 5297, 5303, 5309, 5323, 5333, 5347, 5351, 5381, 5387, 5393, 5399, 5407, 5413, 5417, 5419, 5431, 5437, 5441, 5443, 5449, 5471, 5477, 5479, 5483, 5501, 5503, 5507, 5519, 5521, 5527, 5531, 5557, 5563, 5569, 5573, 5581, 5591, 5623, 5639, 5641, 5647, 5651, 5653, 5657, 5659, 5669, 5683, 5689, 5693, 5701, 5711, 5717, 5737, 5741, 5743, 5749, 5779, 5783, 5791, 5801, 5807, 5813, 5821, 5827, 5839, 5843, 5849, 5851, 5857, 5861, 5867, 5869, 5879, 5881, 5897, 5903, 5923, 5927, 5939, 5953, 5981, 5987, 6007, 6011, 6029, 6037, 6043, 6047, 6053, 6067, 6073, 6079, 6089, 6091, 6101, 6113, 6121, 6131, 6133, 6143, 6151, 6163, 6173, 6197, 6199, 6203, 6211, 6217, 6221, 6229, 6247, 6257, 6263, 6269, 6271, 6277, 6287, 6299, 6301, 6311, 6317, 6323, 6329, 6337, 6343, 6353, 6359, 6361, 6367, 6373, 6379, 6389, 6397, 6421, 6427, 6449, 6451, 6469, 6473, 6481, 6491, 6521, 6529, 6547, 6551, 6553, 6563, 6569, 6571, 6577, 6581, 6599, 6607, 6619, 6637, 6653, 6659, 6661, 6673, 6679, 6689, 6691, 6701, 6703, 6709, 6719, 6733, 6737, 6761, 6763, 6779, 6781, 6791, 6793, 6803, 6823, 6827, 6829, 6833, 6841, 6857, 6863, 6869, 6871, 6883, 6899, 6907, 6911, 6917, 6947, 6949, 6959, 6961, 6967, 6971, 6977, 6983, 6991, 6997, 7001, 7013, 7019, 7027, 7039, 7043, 7057, 7069, 7079, 7103, 7109, 7121, 7127, 7129, 7151, 7159, 7177, 7187, 7193, 7207, 7211, 7213, 7219, 7229, 7237, 7243, 7247, 7253, 7283, 7297, 7307, 7309, 7321, 7331, 7333, 7349, 7351, 7369, 7393, 7411, 7417, 7433, 7451, 7457, 7459, 7477, 7481, 7487, 7489, 7499, 7507, 7517, 7523, 7529, 7537, 7541, 7547, 7549, 7559, 7561, 7573, 7577, 7583, 7589, 7591, 7603, 7607, 7621, 7639, 7643, 7649, 7669, 7673, 7681, 7687, 7691, 7699, 7703, 7717, 7723, 7727, 7741, 7753, 7757, 7759, 7789, 7793, 7817, 7823, 7829, 7841, 7853, 7867, 7873, 7877, 7879, 7883, 7901, 7907, 7919]
n = 1
while True:
    triangle  = n*(n+1)/2
    _triangle = triangle
    prime_factors = []
    for prime in prime_list:
        counter = 0
        while _triangle % prime == 0:
            _triangle /= prime
            counter +=1
        prime_factors.append(counter+1)
    # If triangle = p1^q1*p2^q2*p3^3 ... p1,p2 ... are primes
    # the number of divisors is (q1+1)*(q2+1)*(q3+1)...
    # The math is really simple here:
    # any divisor of triangle can be written as : p1^r1*p2^r2*p3^r3 (r1's range is 0 to q1)
    divisor_num = reduce(lambda a,b : a*b, prime_factors)
    if divisor_num > 500 :
        print triangle
        break
    else:
        n += 1
```

It takes about 5-10s, not very fast but acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, it does give the correct value, what does  if prime*prime > _triangle do in your code, I only got the correct answer when I removed it or used pass?

Comment: Also when removing that line, the code runs consistently over a second faster on my computer around 4.3s.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown below avoids several problems that are present in previously-presented code.

A problem in the original post is counting divisors by testing all numbers less than the number `t` being processed.  Various possible speedups exist: Don't test the numbers between `(t+2)/2` and `t-1`, because none of them can divide `t`.  That could be extended (for example, numbers between `(t+3)/3` and `(t-1)/2` don't need to be tested) but returns diminish rapidly.  A more important speedup is to use a multiplicative form of the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function); for example, if a number `t` equals 
`pᵃ·qᵇ·rᶜ` with `p, q, r` prime, then 
`σ₀(t) = τ(t) = (a+1)·(b+1)·(c+1)`. (The divisor-counting function σ₀ (sigma zero) often is indicated by τ (tau) instead of σ₀.)

A problem in another answer is factoring `(i*(i+1)/2)` or `n*(n+1)/2` at each step.  It is faster to just factor `i+1` or `n+1` at each step, and remember the factors from the previous step.  This cuts execution time by a factor of at least 2.

The code below computes `τ(k·(k+1)/2)` by `τ(k)·τ(k+1)·e/(e+1))`, where `e` represents the exponent of 2 in the product `τ(k)·τ(k+1)`.  That is, because no prime factor of `k` can be a prime factor of `k+1`, and vice versa, `τ(k·(k+1)) = τ(k)·τ(k+1)`; and `τ(k·(k+1)/2)` is smaller than `τ(k·(k+1))` by the ratio `e/(e+1)`.

The attached program runs in about 0.14 seconds on my older computer, when invoked by `findHiTau(120)`.  The parameter to `findHiTau` is an upper limit on size of primes in the program's `oddprimes` table, and is the square root of the highest value of `k` tested; so triangular numbers as large as about `k⁴/2` will be processed.

```
# Returns divisor count for integer v and power of 2 in v
def tau(v):
    p2 = 0
    while v%2 == 0:
        v, p2 = v/2, p2+1
    t = p2+1
    for p in oddprimes:
        if v%p == 0:
            e = 1
            while v%p == 0:
                v, e = v/p, e+1
            t *= e
        if p*p > v: break
    if v>1:                     # Rest of v is a prime
        t *= 2
    return (t, p2)

def findHiTau(primeLim):   # Show record-high values of tau(k*(k+1)/2) up to k=m
    # Make array of small odd primes (expression is ok at least to 100K)
    oddprimes = [3,5,7,11,13]+[x for x in range(17,primeLim,2) if 1==pow(2,x-1,x)==pow(3,x-1,x)==pow(5,x-1,x)==pow(7,x-1,x)==pow(11,x-1,x)==pow(13,x-1,x)]
    taub, e2, hitau = 2, 1, 0       # e2 = exponent of 2
    # In loop, taua = tau(k-1); taub = tau(k); e2 = power of 2 in (k-1)*k
    for k in range(3,primeLim*primeLim):
        taua = taub
        (taub, f2) = tau(k)
        if f2:  e2 = f2         # If f is even, update e2
        ttau = taua*taub*e2/(e2+1)
        if ttau > hitau:
            hitau = ttau
            print '{:3} {:3}  {:3}'.format(k-1, k, ttau)
```